# Sending message in discord using bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I was working on discord.py and I got issue with error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Here is the code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

pybot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", description="I love it",case_insensitive=True)

log_channel_id=674175630916583445

@pybot.event

async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as{pybot.user}")
    channel = pybot.get_user(log_channel_id)
    await channel.send('')

pybot.run(TOKEN, bot=True, reconnect=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get a channel but you're using the `get_user` function. Since the bot can't find a user with the channel's ID, it returns `None`.
Replace

```
channel = pybot.get_user(log_channel_id)
```

with

```
channel = pybot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@pybot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as{pybot.user}")
    channel = pybot.get_channel(674175630916583445)
    await channel.send('')
```

You can have more information about `get_channel` in the official Discord.py docs

- [`get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel)